# How do I transfer a video from an iPhone 3GS to my computer?

Tags: iphone, file-transfer

I recorded a bunch of video on my iPhone 3GS and want to copy it all to my computer without emailing each one individually to myself (in addition, some of the videos are too big to email).  Is there an easy way to do this?  (jailbreak options ok as well)

Comment: Jailbreak and SSH FTW

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**If you're using a Mac:**

You can connect via USB and use ImageCapture.app to import them.

> The Image Capture app should almost
>   instantly see the iPhone attached, and
>   offer up a dialog like the one in the
>   screencap below.  From there you can
>   choose where to download videos or
>   pictures to, whether to download all
>   or make individual selections, and
>   review and modify several other
>   options (e.g whether or not to delete
>   the originals on the iPhone once the
>   import is done).
>
> [image: 3GSpeedy]
>
> Once you’ve made you choices and
>   clicked to download, it shows you a
>   status bar and quickly transfers your
>   videos over to the Mac. Or you can
>   just click to select a video and drag
>   it straight into your desired target
>   folder for it.  I have tested so far
>   with only 30 – 60 second videos, but
>   these zoomed across to the Mac quite
>   nicely.
>
> That’s it – your video files will be
>   available as .mov files wherever you
>   chose to save them too.
>
> [Source](http://justanotheriphoneblog.com/wordpress/iphone-tips/iphone-3gs-tip-how-to-transfer-video-from-iphone-to-mac-quickly)

**If you're using a PC:**

Connect your iPhone via USB. When Windows detects the iPhone, you can open the folder for the iPhone and copy the files to your PC.

Comment: I can't seem to copy from the iphone folder using vista - i end up having to use copytrans - a kool little app for windows

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem for movies above 340 MB, but not for movies a little less than 200 MB.

What worked for me was to do the backup, then look into the Backup folder, usually under something like `C:\Documents and Settings\<userName>\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\<backupId>`.

Sorting by size, it showed files that had the same size as my huge movies. I copied those files and renamed them with a `.mov` extension. Those were the movies. And I was able to see them with QuickTime. I then deleted the movie from the iPhone.

Comment: user nikko says: "Georges Z --- You are a genius Man!" 2010-05-03

Answer (score 1):

I use "MediaTransfer" - it FTPs right off the phone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to run Google Picasa, which has an Import button to import from Camera. I clicked that, selected the folder, then "Import selected", and the file was on my computer in no time.